# NodeJs SQLITE Insert and get the inserted object or last inserted id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am trying to get the object I inserted. I am referring to the example in the
documentation. But I always get an "undefined". What am I doing wrong? Or is it
no longer possible?

In my package.json is the following sqlite3 library `"sqlite3": "^5.0.8"`.

**My code** *(paste and give me the last inserted id)*

```js
sql = `INSERT INTO comment_hearts(post_id, comment_id, user_id, CREATED_AT)
VALUES (?,?,?,?)`
db.run(sql, [1, 100, 10, new Date().toString()], (err) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err.message)};
    console.log("THIS.lastID",this.lastID) // get always undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a callback function with `function () { ... }` for `this.lastID` to not be undefined.

```
db.run(sql, [1, 100, 10, new Date().toString()], function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err.message)};
    console.log("THIS.lastID",this.lastID);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use arrow function. Pass as callback a `function() {...}`. The reason is the context of this. The expression of an arrow function has no this of its own.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions